# Read emails from the Mail App on an iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, email

I am required to read and download emails from the Mail App on an iOS device. I understand that it is possible to fetch emails from the email servers but my requirement is to have access to the emails from all the accounts that have been configured in the Mail App on the device. Is this possible? If yes, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You can *send* emails using [the Message UI framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/index.html), but there is no way to access content in the iOS Mail application from another app.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you tell me how products such as http://www.mobile-spy.com/monitoring_features.html#top monitor email activity?

Comment: @CaesarCipher i have checked the reference you given here and as expected the spy.com software works with jailbroken device only. check the [iphone compatibility page](http://www.mobile-spy.com/compatibility.html)